# Entity Framework/ASP MVC relationship validation: check for key or object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, fluentvalidation

Suppose I have an example entity:

```
public class City
{
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public virtual State State{ get; set; }
}
```

There are a couple of situations where new cities are created.
1) By a user in a view, selecting from existing states:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(it => it.StateId, ViewBag.States)
```

2) On the back end in situations where the state might be new also:

```
State newState = context.States.Create();
newState.Name = "North Takoma";

City newCity = context.Cities.Create();
newCity.Name = "Springfield";
newCity.State = newState;

context.States.Attach(newState);
context.Cities.Attach(newCity);    

context.SaveChanges();
```

The state relationship is required and should be validated.  The question is should we validate on the StateID or the actual State relationship object? (Using FluentValidation here, but would be a fairly similar situation using Data Annotations)

```
public class CityValidator : AbstractValidator<City>
{
    public CityValidator()
    {
        // this?
        RuleFor(it => it.StateID).NotEmpty();

        // or this?
        RuleFor(it => it.State).NotNull();
    }
}
```

In the first situation, the StateID will be populated but not the state object; and vice versa for the second situation.

I could put custom logic in my validator to check for one or the other; however, then I lose the unobtrusive validation attributes in my view.  Any good, DRY solutions to this issue?

**Edit for clarification:** In the example, it is possible to assign a State to a City by setting either the StateID (for an existing state), or the State property (for a new state).  So how can I set up the validation and still get the "data-val-required" attribute on the input in my view?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, User may or may not select the state? am i right?

for your,

**First Case** : StateID will be populated but not the state object.

```
RuleFor(c => c.StateId).NotEmpty().When(s => s.State != null).WithMessage("Please select state.");
```

**Second Case** : vice versa for the second situation

i understand from yo that this will happen at server side, hence you no need the rule for this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I went down that path.  However, I don't believe that the unobtrustive validation attributes will be set when using the .When extension on a rule set.